# MySQL Crashing - Ubuntu 14.04.5 / MYSQL 5.5.53

Tags: mysql, crash

My Mysql instance keeps shutting itself down.

running:  Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
mysql innodb_version 5.5.53

can someone help me make sense of this error log?

```
171004 10:21:30 [Warning] IP address 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
171004 11:07:52 [Warning] IP address 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
171004 11:16:22 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
171004 11:16:22 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
171004 11:16:22 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
171004 11:16:22 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
171004 11:16:22 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
171004 11:16:22 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
171004 11:16:22 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
171004 11:16:22 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
171004 11:16:22 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
171004 11:16:22 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
171004 11:16:22 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
171004 11:16:22 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
171004 11:16:22 [ERROR] Aborting

171004 11:16:22 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

171004 11:16:23 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
171004 11:16:23 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
171004 11:16:23 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
171004 11:16:23 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
171004 11:16:23 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
171004 11:16:23 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
171004 11:16:23 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
171004 11:16:23 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
171004 11:16:23 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
171004 11:16:23 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
171004 11:16:23 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
171004 11:16:23 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
171004 11:16:23 [ERROR] Aborting

171004 11:16:23 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 1):

> 171004 11:16:22 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M.
>   InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12.
>   171004 11:16:22 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool.
>   171004 11:16:22 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool.

You don't have enough memory to start mysql.

Try updating my.cnf to include `innodb_buffer_pool=16M`

Check your memory situation with `free -m`.